# How can I average multiple ROC curves in k-fold Cross-Validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, standard-deviation, roc, mean

I am evaluating a Neural Network performance using 4-fold cross validation. I produced the ROC curve in the picture.

[image]

1) How can I average the folds to obtain just one ROC curve?

2) How can I justify this plot to retain it? 
[ maybe it's useful to plot different folds to see the spread and how stable the model is, could you please explain this? ]

Comment: What do you want to ultimately show? See Frank's answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1863370) too.

Comment: First, I'd like to show just one curve, averaged across all folds. Then, retain this plot, if it's meaningful.

Comment: Do you get probabilities or just hard labels from each of your folds?

Comment: I get probabilities, then I threshold form 0 to 1 with increment 0.001 to obtain the ROC curves.

Comment: Thresholding them seems a bit arbitrary but it shouldn't be a huge influence. Coming back to what I asked originally: What exactly are you trying to ultimately show? Why do you want to average the curves? Are you looking for a single number (say "average AUC" - *which would be wrong*) that encapsulate the performance of your classifier?

Comment: I want to show just one curve which represents the performance of the classifier, and so have one AUC. I want to average them because if I train another classifier in these folds, then would be bad to compare the two classifiers fold by fold.

Comment: Do you want to average points with most similar thresholds (between positive and negative calls), or do you want to average points that give most similar performance? To produce a smooth ROC, I would use the latter; doing the former results in ROCs that appear jagged and not reflective of the average performance. Mathematically, the trouble stems from true positive rate and false positive rate being parametric functions of the threshold between positive and negative calls.

Answer (score 1):

1) Calculate sensitivity and specificity at the incremental thresholds between 0 to 1 for all the folds. Averaging those should give you your desired average ROC Curve.

2)Displaying multiple plots can show you the spread but do not forget that randomly shuffling the same data can result in different spreads as well. The main reason to use cross-validation is mainly motivated by the fact that data spread is random. So try to use cross-validation as a validation tool for your model.